# Force IntelliJ to rerun anntoation processors?

Tags: intellij-idea, annotation-processing

Is there any way to rerun annotation processors without rebuilding the entire project?

I'm developing an annotation processor which is used in project that takes ~ 10 minutes to build from scratch and it's a bit painful to wait 10 mins to test a change...

Answer (score 1):

### General Aspect

This sounds like you don't have a proper testing approach for your annotation processor.

If you do testing always in an integrated environment, you will always have the problem of long running tests. This applys to any test environment that depens on heavy task.

So, my generall advice would be to write lightwight unit tests to check you code is working as expected. That's a general advice I can give you.

This article https://blog.jooq.org/2018/12/07/how-to-unit-test-your-annotation-processor-using-joor/ from Lukas Eder - the founder of JOOQ and that uses java annotation processors as well - is about unit testing java annotation processors.

### Only Run Annotation Processors

#### Intellij Idea

AFAIK there is no way to do this.

#### Maven

If your project runs on maven, you can trigger annotation processors by just execution the `generate-sources` phase.

Comment: The same maven trick should work in IDEA as well, just make a maven run config that triggers this? That said, if the author is writing an annotation processor, then the processor's project likely needs to be built first.

Answer (score 0):

Annotation processor can not be run without the compiler.

If you are not using Maven or Gradle to build the project but is using the IDE's build, invoke the Build | Build Project action. This way IDE will perform an incremental build that will build only changed classes.